# ActionScript3: how to get real url of page in which swf is placed?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mxml, flash-builder

So I tried

```
            var url:String = String(this.loaderInfo.url);
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            try {
                navigateToURL(request, '_self'); // second argument is target
            } catch (e:Error) {
                ErrorButton.label = "Please refresh page manually"
            }
```

and

```
            var url:String = String(this.loaderInfo.loaderURL);
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            try {
                navigateToURL(request, '_self'); // second argument is target
            } catch (e:Error) {
                ErrorButton.label = "Please refresh page manually"
            }
```

and FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.url but it all gives same=(

but thay bouth return me to `http://127.0.0.1/w2/window.swf` while I had url `http://127.0.0.1/w2/window.php?action=read#1`. I use flash builder. So what shall I do to recive real full link - not swf link?

Comment: afaik you can get only the link to the swf physical location from AS3. however you can create an swf container for your current swf and load it there - it'd be easy to keep the link in the parent swf. another way is to make your php server-side return you not just an swf, but an swf embedded in html with the link you need (i think server must know it) passed to your swf file as a get-parameter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about

```
var _url:String = flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("window.location");
```